# ASP.NET Core passing two parameters via Button control

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

In following loop in a View of my `ASP.NET Core 1.1 MVC` app, I'm passing a Primary Key ID for each item as follows. But I need to pass another value `@Model.lstOrders[i].OrderType` via same button as well, how can I achieve that ?

```
@model MyProj.Models.OrdersViewModel
...
@for (int i=0; i< Model.lstOrders.Count; i++)
{
  <tr>
     <td>
         <span>@Model.lstOrders[i].ProductName</span>
      </td>
  <td>
      <button type="button" class="Updatebtn" value="@Model.lstOrders[i].OrderId">Update</button>
  </td>
 <tr>
}
...
```

Comment: Its just a button you can make the value anything you want, it's how you parse and use it "{orderId: @Model.lstOrders[i].OrderId, myOtherId: @Model.lstOrders[i].AnotherId}"

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is to place whatever inside ***for*** loop as individual ***form*** tag. By doing so, you could post as many value as you want to action method.

In additions, you could even create it as Partial View if you want.

```
@for (int i=0; i< Model.lstOrders.Count; i++)
{
   <form id=""@Model.lstOrders[i].OrderId" asp-action="AddToCart"
          asp-controller="Cart" method="post">
      <input type="hidden" asp-for="@Model.lstOrders[i].OrderId" />
      <input type="hidden" asp-for="@Model.lstOrders[i].OrderType" />
      <button type="button" class="Updatebtn">Update</button>
   </form>
}
```

You can read more at Adam Freeman's Pro ASP.NET Core MVC Sample Code - [ProductSummary.cshtml (PartialView)](https://github.com/Apress/pro-asp.net-core-mvc/blob/master/Source%20Code%201-31/12%20-%20SportsStore%20-%20Security%20and%20Deployment/SportsStore/src/SportsStore/Views/Shared/ProductSummary.cshtml), [List.cshtml](https://github.com/Apress/pro-asp.net-core-mvc/blob/master/Source%20Code%201-31/12%20-%20SportsStore%20-%20Security%20and%20Deployment/SportsStore/src/SportsStore/Views/Product/List.cshtml#L4) and [AddToCart ActionMethod](https://github.com/Apress/pro-asp.net-core-mvc/blob/master/Source%20Code%201-31/12%20-%20SportsStore%20-%20Security%20and%20Deployment/SportsStore/src/SportsStore/Controllers/CartController.cs#L24).